# Dead Simple but lengthy Java PrintWriter problem

Tags: java, file-io, printwriter

The problem is it finds the key word "dodge" creates the file but doesn't write to it. I had this problem earlier and I flushing then closing the file fixed it, but that did not work this time.

Also `WriteToFile(CurrentLine[ReturnWordsIndex("using")-1]);` towards the bottom errors out and says `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2` I'm not sure why because "using" should never be found at position -1.

```
import java.io.*;    
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class InputLog {
    private BufferedReader CombatLog;
    private PrintWriter CharacterFile;
    private String[] CurrentLine;

    InputLog(){
        try{
            CombatLog = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("127401175162_chatlog.txt"));
            do{
                try{
                    CurrentLine = CombatLog.readLine().split(" ");
                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry cannot open UserSettings File");
                }
                DetermineType();
                }while(CombatLog.ready());
            CharacterFile.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not open next line of combatlog " + e);
        }
    }
    public void WriteToFile(String S){
        try{
            CharacterFile = new PrintWriter(new File(CurrentLine[3]));
        }
        catch(IOException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry can't write " + CurrentLine[3] +" To file");
        }
        CharacterFile.flush();
        CharacterFile.print(S+ " ");
    }

    public void WriteToFileLn(String S){
        try{
            CharacterFile = new PrintWriter(new File(CurrentLine[3]));
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry can't write " + CurrentLine[3] +" To file");
        }
        CharacterFile.flush();
        CharacterFile.println(S+ " ");
    }


    public int ReturnWordsIndex(String S){
        for(int i=0;i<CurrentLine.length;i++){
            if(CurrentLine[i].equals(S))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private void DetermineType(){
        for(String A: CurrentLine)
            if(A.equals("attacks")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "found dodge");
                WriteToFile(CurrentLine[2]);
                WriteToFile(CurrentLine[ReturnWordsIndex("using")-1]);
                WriteToFile("(dodge).");
                WriteToFileLn(CurrentLine[ReturnWordsIndex("attacks")-1]);
            }
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){
        new InputLog();
    }
}
```

Thanks, Macaire

Edit: I found out that i am simply writing one string, creating a new file, then writing another character. How can i not delete the file, and just rewrite to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i not delete the file, and just rewrite to it?

I assume that you mean *append* to it.  (What you are currently doing is rewriting it.)

If so, just use [`FileWriter(file, true)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) to create a `Writer` that will start writing at the current end of the file; e.g.

```
CharacterFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File(CurrentLine[3])));
```

---

Note: it is bad style for a Java variable or method name to start with an upper-case letter.

Answer (score 0):

`WriteToFile(CurrentLine[ReturnWordsIndex("using")-1]);` causes an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2` because the word "using" is not found (so `ReturnWordsIndex("using")` returns -1).

You need an if/then statement so that you don't try to index `CurrentLine` if the word wasn't found.

Comment: Ah I see thank you. For some reason that caused 1 small piece, a very small piece, of the information, that I expect, to be written to the file using PrintWriter.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your edit, open the file outside of the `WriteToFile` and `WriteToFileLn` functions.